# IdeaVim edit multiple lines at the same time in PhpStorm

Tags: vim, phpstorm, ideavim

I have IdeaVim plugin installed and I'm having trouble editing multiple lines at the same time, but I have seen a few videos on web where people do it properly.

So I select a word using let's say `v + e` and then I do `Alt + j` (I'm using `Ubuntu`) to select multiple occurances in the document, and then if I press `c`, it edits only the first occurance and then just deletes the rest.

I tried loads of key combinations but cannot get it working. Is this not possible to do in IdeaVim? Do I have to toggle the plugin on and off to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Working with multiple carets is not supported by IdeaVim (besides the Visual Block mode, Ctrl+V). Feel free to vote for this feature request [VIM-780](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-780).

Note that you can achieve even better results for editing variable and function names in your code with the Rename refactoring ("Refactor | Rename..."). It will rename all the correct usages of the variable across multiple files.